Why is my simulation in LTspice so much way off from my hand calculation for common gate CMOS?
my circuit is here.

$$
- V_X (g_{m1} + g_{mb1}) + \frac{V_F - V_X} {r_{o1}}
=
0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
\frac{V_F} {V_X}
=
1 + (g_{m1} + g_{mb1}) r_{o1}
$$
$$
\frac{V_X} {V_T}
=
\frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}
$$
$$
\frac{V_F} {V_T}
=
\frac{V_F} {V_X}
\frac{V_X} {V_T}
=
\bigl( 1 + (g_{m1} + g_{mb1}) r_{o1} \bigl)
\frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}
$$

DC analysis.
                        --- MOSFET Transistors ---
Name:          m5          m1
Model:       pmos-sh     nmos-sh
Id:         -1.20e-05    1.20e-05
Vgs:        -7.00e-01    5.25e-01
Vds:        -5.23e-02    1.57e+00
Vbs:         0.00e+00   -1.75e-01
Vth:        -4.20e-01    4.49e-01
Vdsat:      -2.80e-01    7.60e-02
Gm:          4.74e-05    3.17e-04
Gds:         2.08e-04    1.04e-06
Gmb:         1.42e-05    8.47e-05
Cbd:         0.00e+00    0.00e+00
Cbs:         0.00e+00    0.00e+00
Cgsov:       0.00e+00    0.00e+00
Cgdov:       0.00e+00    0.00e+00
Cgbov:       0.00e+00    0.00e+00
Cgs:         0.00e+00    0.00e+00
Cgd:         0.00e+00    0.00e+00
Cgb:         0.00e+00    0.00e+00

Matlab code for hand calculation.
clearvars
g_m1 = 3.17e-04;
g_mb1 = 8.47e-05;

% calculate output resisitance
g_ds = 1.04e-06;
r_o1 = 1/g_ds;

R1 = 1e3;
R2 = 2e3;
A_v1 = ((g_mb1 + g_m1) * r_o1 + 1) * R1 / (R1 + R2)

My hand calculation suggested it's around 129.
But the transfer function gain by spice is less than 1.
ASC files are here.
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 112 16 48 16
WIRE 432 16 112 16
WIRE 736 16 432 16
WIRE 416 32 160 32
WIRE 544 32 416 32
WIRE 48 64 48 16
WIRE 112 64 48 64
WIRE 112 128 112 112
WIRE 160 128 112 128
WIRE 112 144 112 128
WIRE 112 192 -48 192
WIRE 384 224 160 224
WIRE -320 240 -320 176
WIRE -160 240 -160 176
WIRE 384 240 384 224
WIRE 544 240 544 32
WIRE 736 240 736 16
WIRE 112 288 112 240
WIRE 112 288 48 288
WIRE 144 288 112 288
WIRE 240 288 224 288
WIRE 112 304 112 288
WIRE -320 416 -320 320
WIRE -160 416 -160 320
WIRE -160 416 -320 416
WIRE -48 416 -48 192
WIRE -48 416 -160 416
WIRE 112 416 112 384
WIRE 112 416 -48 416
WIRE 240 416 240 368
WIRE 240 416 112 416
WIRE 384 416 384 320
WIRE 384 416 240 416
WIRE 544 416 544 320
WIRE 544 416 384 416
WIRE 736 416 736 320
WIRE 736 416 544 416
WIRE -320 432 -320 416
FLAG -320 432 0
FLAG 432 16 VDD
FLAG 416 32 VB
FLAG 384 224 VG2
FLAG -320 176 Vicm
FLAG -160 176 Vid
FLAG 160 128 Vo
IOPIN 160 128 Out
FLAG 48 288 VX
IOPIN 48 288 Out
SYMBOL nmos4 160 144 M0
WINDOW 123 56 100 Left 2
SYMATTR Value2 l=1u w=20u
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMATTR Value NMOS-SH
SYMBOL pmos4 160 112 R180
WINDOW 123 96 35 Left 2
SYMATTR Value2 l=1u w=20u
SYMATTR InstName M5
SYMATTR Value PMOS-SH
SYMBOL voltage -320 224 R0
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName Vicm1
SYMATTR Value 0.7
SYMBOL voltage -160 224 R0
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value2 AC 1
SYMATTR InstName Vid1
SYMATTR Value 0.5
SYMBOL voltage 544 224 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName VB1
SYMATTR Value 1.1
SYMBOL voltage 736 224 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName VDD1
SYMATTR Value 1.8
SYMBOL bv 384 224 R0
WINDOW 3 -83 103 Left 2
SYMATTR Value V=V(Vicm)
SYMATTR InstName B2
SYMBOL res 96 288 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL res 240 272 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 2k
SYMBOL bv 240 272 R0
SYMATTR InstName B1
SYMATTR Value V=V(Vid)
TEXT -168 -64 Left 2 !.MODEL NMOS-SH nmos(kp=180u,vto=0.4, lambda = {0.1/1}, gamma = 0.5, phi = 0.7)
TEXT -168 -40 Left 2 !.MODEL PMOS-SH pmos(kp=45u,vto=-0.42, lambda = {0.14/1}, gamma = 0.5, phi = 0.7)
TEXT -168 -88 Left 2 !;dc Vicm 0 1.8 0.01
TEXT -168 -112 Left 2 !.tf V(Vo) Vid1
TEXT -160 -144 Left 2 !.op

Latest update with correctly biased cmos.

Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 112 16 48 16
WIRE 432 16 112 16
WIRE 736 16 432 16
WIRE 416 32 160 32
WIRE 544 32 416 32
WIRE 48 64 48 16
WIRE 112 64 48 64
WIRE 112 128 112 112
WIRE 160 128 112 128
WIRE 112 144 112 128
WIRE 112 192 -48 192
WIRE 384 224 160 224
WIRE -320 240 -320 176
WIRE -160 240 -160 176
WIRE 384 240 384 224
WIRE 544 240 544 32
WIRE 736 240 736 16
WIRE 112 288 112 240
WIRE 112 288 48 288
WIRE 144 288 112 288
WIRE 240 288 224 288
WIRE 112 304 112 288
WIRE -320 416 -320 320
WIRE -160 416 -160 320
WIRE -160 416 -320 416
WIRE -48 416 -48 192
WIRE -48 416 -160 416
WIRE 112 416 112 384
WIRE 112 416 -48 416
WIRE 240 416 240 368
WIRE 240 416 112 416
WIRE 384 416 384 320
WIRE 384 416 240 416
WIRE 544 416 544 320
WIRE 544 416 384 416
WIRE 736 416 736 320
WIRE 736 416 544 416
WIRE -320 432 -320 416
FLAG -320 432 0
FLAG 432 16 VDD
FLAG 416 32 VB
FLAG 384 224 VG2
FLAG -320 176 Vicm
FLAG -160 176 Vid
FLAG 160 128 Vo
IOPIN 160 128 Out
FLAG 48 288 VX
IOPIN 48 288 Out
SYMBOL nmos4 160 144 M0
WINDOW 123 56 100 Left 2
SYMATTR Value2 l=1u w=20u
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMATTR Value NMOS-SH
SYMBOL pmos4 160 112 R180
WINDOW 123 96 35 Left 2
SYMATTR Value2 l=1u w=20u
SYMATTR InstName M5
SYMATTR Value PMOS-SH
SYMBOL voltage -320 224 R0
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName Vicm1
SYMATTR Value 0.655
SYMBOL voltage -160 224 R0
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value2 AC 1
SYMATTR InstName Vid1
SYMATTR Value 0.5
SYMBOL voltage 544 224 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName VB1
SYMATTR Value 1.3
SYMBOL voltage 736 224 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName VDD1
SYMATTR Value 1.8
SYMBOL bv 384 224 R0
WINDOW 3 -83 103 Left 2
SYMATTR Value V=V(Vicm)
SYMATTR InstName B2
SYMBOL res 96 288 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL res 240 272 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 2k
SYMBOL bv 240 272 R0
SYMATTR InstName B1
SYMATTR Value V=V(Vid)
TEXT -168 -64 Left 2 !.MODEL NMOS-SH nmos(kp=180u,vto=0.4, lambda = {0.1/1}, gamma = 0.5, phi = 0.7)
TEXT -168 -40 Left 2 !.MODEL PMOS-SH pmos(kp=45u,vto=-0.42, lambda = {0.14/1}, gamma = 0.5, phi = 0.7)
TEXT -168 -112 Left 2 !;dc Vicm1 0 1.8 0.01\n.dc VB1 0 1.8 0.01
TEXT -168 -136 Left 2 !;tf V(Vo) Vid1
TEXT -168 -168 Left 2 !.op

Update with current source.

                        --- MOSFET Transistors ---
Name:          m1
Model:       nmos-sh
Id:          2.91e-06
Vgs:         4.86e-01
Vds:         7.78e-01
Vbs:        -1.69e-01
Vth:         4.48e-01
Vdsat:       3.87e-02
Gm:          1.50e-04
Gds:         2.70e-07
Gmb:         4.03e-05
Cbd:         0.00e+00
Cbs:         0.00e+00
Cgsov:       0.00e+00
Cgdov:       0.00e+00
Cgbov:       0.00e+00
Cgs:         0.00e+00
Cgd:         0.00e+00
Cgb:         0.00e+00

Transfer function in spice.
       --- Transfer Function ---

Transfer_function:   235.629     transfer
vid1#Input_impedance:    1e+020  impedance
output_impedance_at_V(vo):   4.17525e+006    impedance

Updated Value in matlab code
clearvars
g_m1 = 1.50e-04;
g_mb1 = 4.03e-05;

% calculate output resisitance
g_ds = 2.70e-07;
r_o1 = 1/g_ds;

R1 = 1e3;
R2 = 2e3;
A_v1 = ((g_mb1 + g_m1) * r_o1 + 1) * R1 / (R1 + R2)

The value given by matlab is
A_v1 =  235.2716

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
